# Automatically visit a url periodically using Azure

Tags: azure

I have a web application running in Azure where a "job" is triggered by visiting a specific url (to a "page" in that application). What is an easy way to make sure this url is visited in a set interval (in my case, once every month)?

I've done this kind of thing before with a web application hosted at a web hotel. In that case I could setup a CRON job that did exactly what i wanted, that is visited the url at a set interval. This was a feature that the web hotel had in their custom "control panel", I just had to specify the url and the interval.

I'm currently looking at WebJobs in Azure to figure out how they work and if that is a good solution. But maybe there's an easier or better way?

Comment: Have you considered making a nodejs application? Would that be appropriate for your usecase? Just a simple app that visits a specific URL at a set interval

Comment: `I'm currently looking at WebJobs in Azure to figure out how they work and if that is a good solution. But maybe there's an easier or better way?` - Look at Timer Triggered Azure Function. Once the function is triggered you can make an HTTP request to that URL from the function code.

Comment: @nopassport1 I'm new to Azure so I haven't really considered anything. That said, I work primarily with .NET and C# so any solution in that realm would make it easier for me.

Comment: @GauravMantri I will take a look at that! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm currently looking at WebJobs in Azure to figure out how they work
>   and if that is a good solution. But maybe there's an easier or better
>   way?

Look for [`Timer Tiggered Azure Function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) where you can invoke an Azure Function at a pre-determined time interval (once a month in your case). One the function is triggered, you can make an HTTP request to the URL.

Functions under `Consumption Plan` are much more light weight than WebJobs. Considering you would be invoking this Function just once a month, it will be much cheaper than WebJobs as well.